# Soundcloud Widget not firing FINISH event in Safari

Tags: safari, coffeescript, widget, soundcloud

I am using the SoundCloud's javascript library to setup some external controls for an embedded player on my site. The play/pause and skip buttons work across all the browsers I've tested (lets leave mobile for another question). I also have wired up a `FINISH` listener to automatically skip the player to a new track. This works on Chrome and Firefox but it seems the event is never triggered on Safari. I will try to pull out the relevant parts of the code and leave out what I believe to be superfluous. Please feel free to ask for clarification or more details.

Thanks!

```
<div id=playlist-player">
  <iframe id="sc-ilovemakonnen-tuesday-feat-drake" class="player-iframe" width="100%" height="120" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/162777996&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
</div>

initializeSoundCloudPlayer: (post) ->
    playerIframe = document.getElementById("sc-"+post.slug)
    @player = SC.Widget(playerIframe)
    @player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, () =>
      @player.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH)
      @player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, () =>
        @skip("forward", true)
      )
    )
```

So the take home message, as I see it, is that `@skip()` method never runs on safari, so I suppose the `FINISH` event is never triggered.

I have read other places that there were problems with some events not being triggered when the autoplay option was true in the embed code but I have this issue with or without autoplay being true.

Comment: Could you paste problematic code to jsbin or jsfiddle? Thanks!

Comment: hey @gryzzly , I am facing the same issue, though in js. here is a fiddle to demonstrate the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/wqp8f6e4/1/

Comment: @kapv89 you gotta attach the handler within the READY callback. Otherwise there's nothing to attach the handler to. There was also a typo with the widget url – see here – http://jsfiddle.net/wqp8f6e4/3/ . Hope this helps!

Comment: hey sorry, i've been sick. i'll get my fiddle up today. EDIT: Actually, just tried your fiddle in safari and the FINISH event was triggered. This is hopeful.  :)